# Japanese custom: Sushi chef serves you small snacks you didn't order?

Tags: japan, local-customs, etiquette, restaurants

I've been to several restaurants, usually sushi oriented, where I will sit down and order a drink (alcoholic), then within a few minutes of receiving my drink, the chef will either walk out and personally serve me a dish I didn't order, or if I'm sitting at the (sushi) bar, he will plop a dish in front of me and explain to me what it is (even though I have demonstrated that I don't speak a lick of japanese).

The dish is what I would call an appetizer; it's like minced sushi fish with sauce, or a small sticky fungus dish, or like a soup with daikon and tofu and what the chef called "pudding".

Usually I smile and nod/half-bow and repeatedly say "arigato thank you" at any brief pause while he's talking.

Also, most times I don't actually order any food, I just get drinks.  This situation exclusively happens for my after work drinks where I'm heading elsewhere to get actual dinner meal.  **Is it rude** to get served the dish I didn't order, consume said dish, and then leave (having only ordered drinks)?  I don't think I've ever been charged beyond the price of the drinks and tax and service charges.

**So my question is**, is this a common Japanese custom or practice? If so, what is the name of this custom? What is the meaning behind it? And what is the proper response?

Comment: Why do you want to only drink in a sushi restaurant/bar? It is a place that serves sushi.

Comment: I assume it's similar to restaurants in the US putting out a free dish of bread or (in Mexican restaurants) tortilla chips and salsa.  There's also the concept of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amuse-bouche, which are "different from appetizers in that they are not ordered from a menu by patrons but are served gratis and according to the chef's selection alone."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is known as **[otōshi](https://matcha-jp.com/en/1625)**.

> Otōshi is a simple dish intended to whet the customers’ appetite
>   before their food arrives and is provided for each person, or is to be
>   shared at the table, **without being ordered**. The charge for otōshi is
>   added onto the total bill for food, so someone visiting an izakaya for
>   the first time might be confused by this.

Comment: Note: It is possible to attempt to refuse it (and I have sometimes been successful), but most places (at least the ones I have been to) will still try and charge you for it anyway. In the end it is easier to accept this as a "service charge" and factor it in to you spending calculations.